# Disable touchscreen before login (in the greeter)

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm, touchscreen

Recently I broke the screen of my Asus x200e and the tactile does random thing. I manually disable the touchscreen with

```
xinput disable ID
```

I need to do that everytime I restart. It's not a big issue because i just alt ctrl t - f11 and I can write my command without the mouse unfocusing the terminal and it just take a few secondes.

But my prob is that I have no option to disable the touchscreen during the ubuntu install (xubuntu ou ubuntu) and i can't disable the touchscreen before the login (greeter).

Do you have an idea ?

Thank's a lot, sorry for my English, I'm a baguette ... I mean, I'm french.

*PS : Do you know if I can remove the touch glass on my screen ? Is the screen under the "touch" glass a normal screen ? Thank's*

**CONFIG : xubuntu 16.04 dual boot win10 - x200e 11.6" i3-3217u 4go**

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/910/602680) and try and save `xinput disable ID`  to a `.conf` file in `/etc/init`

Comment: Tank's a lot, i'm going to try that

Answer (score 0):

I would add `xinput disable "whatever is the name of your touch screen"` to your start up. To find the name of your device, run `xinput`.

For example, here is my start up:

```
xinput disable "ELAN Touchscreen"
```